# Re evaluating time based actions when the field value is changed with process builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, process-builder

Criteria starts: when a record is created or edited.
In order time based actions to appear I selected "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?"
Now I want set time based action based on date field, let's say fire a rule 60 days after.

**The problem** is that if my criteria were already met and when my date field changes I can't reset time based actions (because criteria were already met before and the rule won't be triggered).

`Ischanged` formula isn't available.

Any options?

Comment: if your criteria already met in past then I think it will trigger in next 1 hour

Answer (score 1):

If you select "Formula evaluates to true" rather than "Conditions are met" in the Criteria, you can use ISCHANGED(field)